# What is the MGF of $X_{(1)}$ when $X_1,X_2$ are i.i.d Gamma variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions, order-statistics, gamma-distribution

I want to find the moment generating function (MGF) of the order statistic $X_{(1)}$ where $X_1, X_2$ are iid $\Gamma(\alpha, 1)$.

First attempt was to simply find the order statistic pdf in the usual way, followed by finding the the MGF in the usual way. However, things got tricky when calculating the CDF for the gamma distribution.  I think there is a trick that I might be missing.

EDIT:

This is the pdf for the version of the gamma distribution I am using:

$$f(x) = \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma (\alpha)} x^{\alpha -1} e^{-\beta x}$$

Comment: In case $\Gamma(\alpha,1)$ is simply an exponential distribution, then $X_{(1)}$ also has an exponential distribution.

Comment: I am using the Gamma formula $f(x) = \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma (\alpha)} x^{\alpha -1} e^{-\beta x}$, which is not an exponential distribution when $\Gamma(\alpha, 1)$

Comment: Better add the pdf of $\Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ in the post.

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDF for your $\Gamma(\alpha,1)$ distribution can be written in terms of the Whittaker M function:

$$F(x) = \frac{x^{\alpha/2} e^{-x/2}}{\Gamma(\alpha+2)} M(\alpha/2,(1+\alpha)/2,x) + \frac{x^\alpha e^{-x} (1+\alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha+2)}$$

Comment: This is about where I was at.  Hoping there was some weird special property that made this problem a little nicer.  All well. Thanks for the comment!